# Find the area of a triangle if its two sides measure $6 in.$ and $9 in.$, and the bisector of the angle between the sides is $4\sqrt{3}$ in.

Tags: geometry

Find the area of a triangle if its two sides measure $6$ in. and $9$ in., and the bisector of the angle between the sides is $4\sqrt{3}$ in. I'm thinking of using the formula $A$=$\frac{1}{2}bh$ I can't find the base or height, I used the Angle bisector formula which is $l=$$\frac{\sqrt{ab[(a+b)^2-c^2]}}{a+b}$ So i found out C which i think is the base should i multiply it by $2$? because I think it's the half. From here I'm lost

Comment: have you ever heard of Erone formula for the area?

Comment: @exodd no sorry I'm just relying on my handbook is it okay if you give me hint so I can try it out?

Comment: Do you have any other equation for the area? I don't think $A=bh/2$ will work here..

Comment: @exodd I know the SAS formula, can this one work?

Comment: Yes, if you know a bit of goniometry that works

Comment: @exodd can you give me more hint? like the way to solve it. I'm not sure of my drawing if this is it. Sorry I took my geom. 2yrs ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18883/discussion-between-exodd-and-mickey).

Comment: @Mickey: In English, it's called [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the lengths of two sides $a$ and $b$, and the angle $\theta$ between them, then the area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin \theta$. Let's label the sides $a = 6$, $b = 4\sqrt 3$, and $c = 9$, and the half-angle as $\theta$. The sum of each sub triangle area must equal the total triangle area:
$$A = \frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta + \frac{1}{2}bc\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}ac\sin2\theta $$
Solving this,
$$ ab\sin\theta + bc\sin\theta = ac\sin2\theta = 2ac\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
$$ \cos\theta = \frac{b(a+c)}{2ac} = \frac{5}{3\sqrt 3}$$
Then,
$$\sin\theta = \sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{3}} \qquad \sin2\theta = \frac{10\sqrt 2}{27}$$
And so the area is
$$ A = \frac{1}{2}ac\sin 2\theta = 10\sqrt 2 \text{ sq. in.} $$

Comment: It is worth observing that the general case for side lengths $a$, $b$, and included angle bisector length $k$, the area is $$|\triangle ABC| = \frac{(a+b)k}{4ab} \sqrt{(2ab - (a+b)k)(2ab + (a+b)k)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the SAS formula for solving this.
Note that the bisector divides the triangle in two triangles, so you can use the formula on both of them, and on the original triangle.

Comment: should i still use the angle bisector formula to find $c$? or just stick with the SAS formula?

Comment: you don't need $c$

Comment: alright thanks I'll try

Comment: from the one side is it $A=\frac{9}{2}\frac{s}{2}sin4\sqrt{3}$? because I half the base and I don't know what it is so just $\frac{s}{2}$?

Comment: ? $4\sqrt{3}$ is the lenght of a segment, not an angle..

Comment: so that's the altitude?

Answer (score 0):

Let $|BC|=a$, $|AC|=b$, $|AB|=c$,
angle bisector $|AD|=\beta_a$ in $\triangle ABC$.

Given $b=6,\ c=9,\ \beta_a=4\sqrt3$, find the area $S_{ABC}$.

Using known expression for the length of the angle bisector,
\begin{align} 
\beta_a&=bc\left(
1-\frac{a^2}{(b+c)^2}
\right)
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

the missing side length is found as

\begin{align} 
a&=(b+c)\sqrt{1-\frac{\beta_a^2}{bc}}
=5
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

and the area is found as usual by Heron’s formula

\begin{align} 
S_{ABC}&=
\tfrac14\,\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}
=10\sqrt2
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Or, in terms of the given lengths,

\begin{align} 
S_{ABC}&=
\tfrac14\,\beta_a\,(b+c)\,\sqrt{4-\beta_a^2\,(\tfrac1b+\tfrac1c)^2}
=10\sqrt2
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}